# Rename directory in jenkins with shell cmd

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to run a shell script in jenkins to rename a directory to add the date on it .

```
// rename file
sh("mv $file-reports $file-reports-$date")
sh("mv $file-reports-$date jmeter-tests")
```

date is get by this next script :

```
    // Getting date
    date = sh(
        script: """
                    (date +%T-"%F")
                    """,
        returnStdout: true
    )
```

***output of date :*** 12:55:39-2018-07-26

im getting this error in the log :

```
[Pipeline] sh
[workspace] Running shell script
+ mv quickquote-belair-appstatic-reports quickquote-belair-appstatic-reports-15:59:27-2018-07-26a
[Pipeline] sh
[workspace] Running shell script
+ mv -T quickquote-belair-appstatic-reports-15:59:27-2018-07-26a
mv: missing destination file operand after ‘quickquote-belair-appstatic-reports-15:59:27-2018-07-26a’
Try 'mv --help' for more information.
```

I'm confused on why its telling me there's a missing destination file ..?

Comment: Is it possible to have `:` as part of a file name in linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of `sh()` will followed by an new line as default, so you need to use `trim()` to remove the new line at the end as following:

```
date = sh(
        script: """
                    (date +%T-"%F")
                    """,
        returnStdout: true
    ).trim()
```

Becasue `$date` has a newline at the end, so that `mv $file-reports-$date jmeter-tests` will be broken at `mv $file-reports-$date` the destination `jmeter-tests` move into next line. So it report `mv miss destination file`